# Remove specified elements from a list in a txt file

Tags: python

I have a text file with a 1825 x 51 table. I am attempting to read into the text file and write this table to a new text file while removing certain columns from the table. I couldn't figure out how to delete a whole column because the list is a string so I am attempting to go into each row and use an if/else statement to determine if the element is in the desired range. If it is, write it to output, otherwise delete it.

```
 if i in range(1,3)+[14]+range(20,27)+range(33,38)+[43]+[45]:
     newNum=data[i]
     data[i]=newNum
 else:
     delete.data
```

This is my first time using python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

*code from comments*

```
with open(inputfilepath,'r') as f:
    outputfile=open(outputfilepath,'w+')
    inSection=False
    for line in f:
        if begin in line:inSection=True
        if inSection:
            keep=range(1,3)+[14]+range(20,27)+range(33,38)+[43]+[45]
            tmp=[]
            spl=line.split('  ')
            for idx in keep:
                tmp.extend(spl[idx])
            outputfile.write('%s\n' % '  '.join(tmp))            
        if end in line:inSection=False
```

Comment: The `csv` module may be useful to you.

Comment: Are your columns fixed width or delimited?

Comment: What is wrong with processing the input line-by-line and removing the unwanted fields from every line?

Comment: Could you provide an sample input file and the desired output format? From your questions it is not quite clear what is used to delimit the fields in the input file.

Comment: Columns are fixed width and how would I remove the unwanted fields from every line?

Comment: @exhuma it seems like its delimited by spaces

Comment: Do you have access to a unixy environment (Linux or cygwin maybe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go with something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function


def process(infile, keep):
    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split()
        yield ' '.join([_ for i, _ in enumerate(fields) if i in keep])


def main(infile, outfile):
    # The following line (taken from your example) will not work in Python 3 as
    # you cannot "add" ranges to lists. In Python 3 you would need to write:
    # >>> [14] + list(range(20, 27)
    keep = range(1, 3) + [14] + range(20, 27) + range(33, 38) + [43] + [45]
    for newline in process(infile, keep):
        print(newline, file=outfile)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('so.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        main(infile, outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, it has to be in Python. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No worries. I updated the answer with a pure-python solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
keep = [1,2,3,14,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,33,34,35,36,37,38,43,45]
with open('textfile') as fin, open('textout') as fout:
   for ln in fin:
       tmp = []
       spl = ln.split(' ')
       for idx in keep:
           tmp.append(spl[idx])
       fout.write('%s\n' % ' '.join(tmp))
```

Comment: `tmp = []` needs to be inside the `for ln in fin:` loop. Otherwise, it's going to get rather big... :) Alternatively, Append a '\n' to it after each line and join it & write it when all the data's been read. Also, `keep = range(1,3)+[14]+range(20,27)+range(33,38)+[43]+[45]` is perfectly cromulent, and a bit easier to read than your list.

Comment: Still can't get it work. Getting an "list index out of range" error on line 29. see code below. thanks!